# Ubuntu 12.04 apache2 site shows index of instead of actual site on redmine

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl, https

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server that has a successful redmine install on it.  I have been using redmine on it for a while, but when I tried to set up the SSL cert using this method, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04.

My https:// version of the site just shows my "index of /" instead of the actual site.  If I go to the old http:// it still successfully shows the site.  The only thing that I've done which isn't standard practice (to the best of my knowledge) is to change my default DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available to /var/www/redmine, from the standard /var/www/.

I have made sure that my pages default-ssl document root is also /var/www/redmine (which is where my symbolic link to the actual redmine folder is).

If you need anymore information I'd be happy to post it.  Thanks,

Comment: Can you please paste your configurations?

Comment: Sorry, since this was asked more than 3 years ago, I don't think I still have the server around.  I'm sure I figured it out, but I can't remember what fixed it.  Also, it's completely my fault that I didn't update this question with an answer.  I apologize.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that was an ancient post, lol. How could it appear on the top pages?